# Why onClick deleting all the items in the redux array in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react app where I have implemented a onClick button but that onClick button is deleting all the elements in the redux store array even when I am trying to filter and delete.Here are my codes:

`reducerFunction`

```
case Actions.DELETE_API_GRANT:{
      return{
        ...state,clientAccessGrants:[state.clientAccessGrants.filter(item=>action.grant.api!==item.api)]
      }
    }
```

`My UI Component:`

```
     deleteApiGrants(grant)
  {
    this.props.deleteApiGrants(grant)
  }
    {this.props.clientAccessGrants.map((grant, index) => (
              console.log(grant.api),
              <tr key={grant.api+grant.group}>
                <td>{grant.api}</td>
                
                <td>{grant.group}</td>
                
                <td>
                  <div>
                    <input type='button' value="delete" className='btn' onClick={()=>this.deleteApiGrants({api:grant.api,group:grant.group})}></input>
                    
                  </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
```

`My array object structure is:`

```
{
api:"something",
group:"something"
}
```

`My map and dispatch function:`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

  deleteApiGrants:(grant)=>dispatch(onDeleteApiGrant(grant))
});


 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

  clientAccessGrants:state.client.clientAccessGrants
});
```

`My ActionCreator:`

```
export function onDeleteApiGrant(grant)
{
  console.log(grant)
  return {type:Actions.DELETE_API_GRANT,grant}
}
```

Any help will highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In reducer function, don't enclose output of `*.filter(...)` in square brackets. filter returns an array, and you're creating array of array, which results in invalid data.

Comment: thanks,it worked.Can you propse a proper answer so that I can upvote it and someone else stuck can use it?

Comment: Use clientAccessGrants: [...state.clientAccessGrants.filter(item => item !== action.grant.api)]

Comment: @rudeTool Sure. posted.
@Rahul no need to destructure it again since `Array.filter(...)` will create a new reference already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct your `reducerFunction` to this:

```js
case Actions.DELETE_API_GRANT:{
      return{
        // remove square brackets
        ...state,clientAccessGrants: state.clientAccessGrants.filter(item=>action.grant.api!==item.api)
      }
    }
```

### Reasoning

From [Array.prototype.filter() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#return_value),

> ## Return value
>
> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.